# Check for time difference of 60 seconds for reports downloaded by a user

Tags: php, mysql

I'm facing a problem in multiple data entry check for library users.

Each time a user clicks on a download link, we store it in a table.
What I need is to check that if the same user downloads same report, using same IP and on same date, it should check that the difference between last inserted datetime and current datetime should be more than 60 seconds else skip. The problem is that it stores for all n no. of users data of our library.

Query that I am using:

```
select * from tbl_download group by rcode, date, ip order by date desc where libraryuser_id=11
```

Tbl_download

```
Rcode          Date                  IP            PrimaryID     Libraryuser_id
 A      2014-03-03 14:39:06     192.168.1.2            1              11
 A      2014-03-03 14:39:13     192.168.1.2            2              11
 A      2014-03-03 14:40:17     192.168.1.2            3              11
 B      2014-03-03 14:44:06     192.168.1.3            4              11
 B      2014-03-03 14:44:18     192.168.1.3            5              11
 B      2014-03-03 14:55:06     192.168.1.3            6              11
```

Output that I want -

```
Rcode          Date                  IP            PrimaryID     Libraryuser_id
 A      2014-03-03 14:39:06     192.168.1.2            1              11
 A      2014-03-03 14:40:17     192.168.1.2            3              11
 B      2014-03-03 14:44:06     192.168.1.3            4              11
 B      2014-03-03 14:55:06     192.168.1.3            6              11
```

Let me know for any question? 
Thanks & regards,
Sumantto

Answer (score 0):

So what you need is the time difference between now and the last download :

```
SELECT
  MAX(`date`) - NOW() AS `time_since_last_dl`
FROM `tbl_download`
WHERE 1=1
  AND `libraryuser_id` = {{ USER_ID }}
  AND `ip` = {{ USER_IP }}
  AND `reportcode` = {{ THE_REPORT_CODE }}
```

On your download page, you just have tou check whether or not `time_since_last_dl` meet your requirements (i.e. is greater than 60 seconds)

If you'd like to get this data for every report for one specific `(user, IP)` couple, just add a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT
  reportcode,
  MAX(`date`) - NOW() AS `time_since_last_dl`
FROM `tbl_download`
WHERE 1=1
  AND `libraryuser_id` = {{ USER_ID }}
  AND `ip` = {{ USER_IP }}
GROUP BY
  reportcode
```

Comment: Hi there, I was searching stackoverflow and got a nice solution but it solves 85% of my problem not 100%. The URL is

Comment: I want to have a group by reportcode, date , ip where this check will be only for same reports being listed within 60 seconds, they are to be skipped. If same report is downloaded after 60 seconds then it is acceptable.

Comment: Just add the corresponding conditions in the `WHERE` clause. I'll update the answer